# How to get list of Wikipedia pages need edit based on categories selection?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api

How to take a list of pages which need edit based on categories and sub-categories by using MediaWiki API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If assuming that all Wikipedia pages that need edit include [Template:Cleanup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Cleanup), which means that all they will be placed in [Category:All articles needing cleanup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:All_articles_needing_cleanup), to get a list of all them by using MediaWiki API you have two variants:

**Variant 1:** Get all articles which include **Template:Cleanup** with **[embeddedin](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bembeddedin)**:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&einamespace=0&eititle=Template:Cleanup
```

**Variant 2:** Get all articles from **Category:All articles needing cleanup** with **[categorymembers](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcategorymembers)**:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmnamespace=0&cmtitle=Category:All articles needing cleanup
```

Comment: Just a clarification because I am new in wikipedia data. With clean up we mean pages which need either editing or styling or they have break links and they need update etc. right?

Comment: According https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Cleanup the cleanup issues include page layout, wikification, spelling, grammar and typographical errors, tone, and sourcing.

Comment: Thank you very much. So to sum up I need both variants as you listed them to find the articles needed editing?

Comment: No, all articles with **Template:Cleanup** are automatically added to **Category:All articles needing cleanup** so you need to get all articles with this template (variant 1) or to get all articles in the category (variant 2). Just choose one of the both.